# AngularJS and AngularUI Bootstrap doubling tabs when adding a new tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to build a reusable directive (with isolated scope) for each new AngularUI tab. When I try to collect all the data inside a tab and add a new tab, what Angular actually does is to double my existing tabs and collect the data for each existing tab, each time I press "Add new tab".

Please see the following [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/CJeqQ88lRmoysFJhxUSm/).

Basically, the Add new tab button will broadcast a collectDataFromCurrentTab message that is treated inside TabController. See below:

```
app.controller('TabController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
console.log("Scope id in tab is: " + $scope.$id);

$rootScope.$on('collectDataFromCurrentTab', collectDataFromTab);

function collectDataFromTab() {
    console.log("Scope id in collectDataFromCurrentTab: " + $scope.$id);
    var collector = {};
    collector.currentName = $scope.name;
    collector.currentAddress = $scope.address;

    $rootScope.collectedData.push(collector);

    console.log("Collected data: " + collector.currentName + " - " + collector.currentAddress);

    $rootScope.$broadcast('addNewTab');
}

app.controller('NavigationController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
$scope.addNewTab = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('collectDataFromCurrentTab');
}
```

Any idea on any workaround on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your `$rootScope.$broadcast('addNewTab');` inside your `$scope.addNewTab` function in your `NavigationController`. Dont broadcast `addNewTab` from your `TabController`, since you have multiple Tab $scopes, your were broadcasting multiple times `addNewTab`. Make sure you fix your plunker, you have `NavigationController` repeated twice.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please select my answer if you can. Glad to help.